# Empty Result for SOSL Query List

Tags: visualforce, controller, query, account, sosl

New dev here and I am trying to make a SOSL query to pull accounts that contain a string variable. Not returning any results. Any guidance is appreciated

Here's the vfp

```
<apex:page controller="SoslTestClass">
    <apex:pageBlock>
        <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!accList}" var="acc">
            <apex:column >
                <apex:facet name="header">Account Name</apex:facet>
                <apex:outputText value="{!acc.Name}"/>
            </apex:column>
            <apex:column >
                <apex:facet name="header">Website</apex:facet>
                <apex:outputText value="{!acc.Website}"/>
            </apex:column>
        </apex:pageBlockTable>
    </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:page>
```

And the Apex code

```
public with sharing class SoslTestClass {
    Public List<account> accList{get;set;}
    Public String webName = '.com';

    Public void soslSearch(){
        accList = New List<account>();
        List<List<sObject>> searchList = [FIND :webName IN ALL FIELDS RETURNING Account(Name, Website)];
        accList = ((List<account>)searchList[0]);
        return;
    }
}
```

Comment: Seems fine to me. Are you sure you actually have any matching data?

Comment: Yes, I have multiple accounts that contain '.com' in their website (string field)

Answer (score 2):

I ran your code exactly as you have it and it runs just fine.

If you are running it from your page, I do not see an action to perform the search so how are you executing the search?

Per you comment:

To Execute your code on page load:

1. In the constructor, call the `soslSearch()` method

OR

2. Add an action parameter to the page tag and set it to `{!soslSearch}`

If you are running this during a test methods or the data you think you have is not present.

SOSL executed from test methods needs to have the resultant IDs hardcoded during the test:

> To ensure that test methods always behave in a predictable way, any
>   Salesforce Object Search Language (SOSL) query that is added to an
>   Apex test method returns an empty set of search results when the test
>   method executes. If you do not want the query to return an empty list
>   of results, you can use the Test.setFixedSearchResults system method
>   to define a list of record IDs that are returned by the search

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_testing_SOSL.htm

**example output from your code**

```
Executing:
======================================================================================================== 
 Public List<account> accList{get;set;} 
 String webName = '.com'; accList = New      
 List<account>(); List<List<sObject>> searchList = [FIND :webName IN ALL FIELDS RETURNING Account(Name, Website) Limit 1]; 
 accList =((List<account>)searchList[0]);

system.debug(accList); 

======================================================================================================== Success.
```

> 19:25:59.19 (51817077)|USER_DEBUG|[7]|DEBUG|(Account:{Name=xxxxxx.com /
>   xxxxxxx.com B2C, Id=001a00000xxxxxxxx})

Comment: Ah yes, they could just change `void soslSearch` to `List<Account> getAccList`.

Comment: I would like to execute the search on page load

Comment: @asdkhalifa - See updated answer